# Running PHP code with SAPUI5 on HANA Cloud Platform

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, sapui5, sap-cloud-platform

I tried to write some data with PHP in an .txt file so that I can create in my SAPUI5 App the file "writeData.php" with this content:

```
<?php 
  $inhalt = "123456789";
  $handle = fopen ("testWrite.txt", w);
  fwrite ($handle, $inhalt);
  fclose ($handle);
?>
```

Then I try to call this file with the following Ajax request:

```
writeStringToWhitelist: function(newContent){
        $.ajax({
            url: "writeData.php",
            type: "GET",
            data: newContent,
            async: false,
            success: function(){
                console.log("Success");
            }
        });
    }
```

I know that there are surely some mistakes, but I hope someone can help me!

Thanks in regards

Comment: What exactly is the problem?

Answer (score 1):

As of now, SAP HANA Cloud Platform does not support PHP (yet). With the upcoming Cloud Foundry, PHP support seems likely, but as far as I know this is not released yet.

Nevertheless, you can also easily write your script in **Java**. HANA Cloud Platform (HCP) has a great Java support. For more information, read the [HCP Java Documentation](https://help.hana.ondemand.com/help/frameset.htm?9bd4dd19aef947b58eadf688ccc90de7.html).

When you do that, make sure that you only start a write request when doing a **HTTP POST**, and not a **HTTP GET**. Every HTTP request method fullfills a certain action. Here you can read more about the [definition of HTTP requests methods](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hypertext_Transfer_Protocol#Request_methods).